# do we have hidden files in .git by default?

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and learning git, I understood .git file is a hidden file inside of my directory after I use `git init`, my question is does the .git folder have hidden files inside of it by default?

Comment: Just to clarify, the `.git` folder _is the git repository_.

Answer (score 1):

The `.git` folder is hidden to prevent accidental deletion or modification of the folder. The version history of the code base will be lost if this folder is deleted. This means, we will not be able to rollback changes made to the code in future.

Edit: The files INSIDE `.git` are not hidden. Just the folder is.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no.  On a Unix system, files that start with a dot are not listed by default by `ls` and similar tools and are generally considered "hidden".  Within the `.git` folder, files and directories are not typically created starting with a dot, although non-Git tools which interoperate with Git could theoretically create them.

On Windows, the hidden attribute is a specific file system attribute for a file.  Git for Windows can hide either all dotfiles or only `.git` files and directories.  Since Git for Windows doesn't generally hide other files, unless another tool has created them, no, there won't be hidden files in `.git`.